# attach Child Window at the bottom of it's Parent

Tags: c, api, window, parent-child

I'm having a little trouble with win32 API, C language.

So, this is what's happening:
I need to make a Child Window to stay on the botton of it's Parent Window, like a footer. I'm using math to position the window from GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN), but happens that from screen to screen the "footer" doesn't correspond to the same variables.

How can I make the Child Window Stay on the bottom of its parent?

I've been searching a LOT but couldn't find nothing usefull

Answer (score 0):

Use [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `X` and `Y` parameters are not absolute coordinates but are relative to the upper-left corner of the parent window's client area.

Comment: So should I measure the height of the client area and then subtract with the size of the window I want to atach?

Comment: `X` and `Y` are the coordinates relative to the parent window -- so, if the parent window is at 100,200 with width=300 and height=400, and the child window is width=80 and height=90, you would give X=220 (= 300 - 80) and Y=310 (400 - 90)